# socket.io connection from specific page

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

On my website, I have different different pages, each page has javascript that contains

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
```

On the app.js (server file), it's coded so that everytime it receives a connection, it'll do something, no matter which page the client is from.

```
io.sockets.on ('connection', function (socket) { 
    // do something
});
```

However, I'd like the app.js to execute different action depending on the page client is from, is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.There are two ways:

1) You may send a header along with the data from client.
You may retrieve it this way:

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent"); //ter accepting connec Browser identifier.
String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

2) Alternatively you may send a extra variable that stores the ID number of the client And in the server side you may store all client ID's in an array and after accepting connection, you may determine using if-else, as to which ID the client matches and execute task accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you send the current page to the server, or just send location.href to make it universal for every page. SocketIO can not magically see what page the request is coming from.